Stacking UVs in Geometry nodes
Is there any nodes stack UV?
I have marked seams and unwrapped using unwrap node.
But cant see way to stuck them. Looking to try stack top and bottom faces.


Do you mean pinning? There's no option to pin currently.

Not sure on term. will look it up.

Oh, well, pinning looks good. but was looking to get them to stack before get thinking about extra packs.  I guess only way is to write own node. that i can input top and bottom seam and place them on top each other.
